# Quarkus: Smallrye Metrics are enabled, why aren't they shown on Dev UI? Or on Swagger?

Tags: quarkus, smallrye

I'm trying my first steps with Quarkus metrics, using SmallRye. I enabled it and it works when I call http://localhost:8080/api/metrics/application (my `quarkus.http.non-application-root-path` is `api`).

But although I see other SmallRye parts in the Dev UI (SmallRye Health, SmallRye OpenAPI), the SmallRye Metrics is inactive (gray, can't be clicked). Why is that? Am I missing some configuration?

Also, it would be great if the metrics showed up on the Swagger UI, since Swagger really shows everything that the service can do. It works great with SmallRye Health, but not with SmallRye Metrics. How can I achieve that?

Comment: As mentioned in https://quarkus.io/guides/micrometer, Micrometer is the recommended approach to metrics these days. Can you try and see if things work as expected with it?

Comment: After replacing `quarkus-smallrye-metrics` with `quarkus-micrometer-registry-prometheus`, the SmallRye Metrics doesn't exist anymore in the Dev UI. I can see both `Micrometer Registry Prometheus` and `Micrometer metrics`, but both are inactive.

Comment: P.S. Yassu to Greece  :-)

Comment: Hm.. I guess we have not implemented any DevUI entry for micrometer. I assume that is because all the metrics are exposed under `/q/metrics`

Comment: Ok, that's fine by me. But having it on the Dev UI makes it confusing, if it will never exist.